# What are the pros/cons of SSD vs RAID 0 in the alienware laptops?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, ssd, raid, raid-0

I'm considering purchasing a new Alienware laptop for my software development and testing work. I'm looking at the M15 R3. I'm hung up on the hard drive choices. The Dell config page give 2 choices: SSD or RAID 0:
[image: SSD vs RAID 0]

As you can see, those two options are exactly the same price for the same GB of storage. My understanding has always been that SSD's are more expensive compared to HDD's because SSD's are faster and more reliable (less prone to breakage, because no moving parts). So I am a little baffled as to why the HDD is the same price as the SSD. I'm not familiar with RAID 0, so my thinking is that there is some benefit that RAID 0 would give me that the SSD does not have. But I don't know what that could be. Upon clicking the "Help Me Choose" link (https://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/help-me-choose/cp/hmc-hdd-consumer), the description on the opened page describes pretty much what I have already said:  Solid-state drives are lightweight and cooler than standard hard drives, they greatly outperform HDDs in read/write speeds, they have improved performance and durability, and that they are better for mobile users. That page also says that the cost per GB on an HDD is lower compared to SSD. If that's the case, then why are the RAID 0's (HDD's) priced exactly the same as the SSD's? I must be missing something.

My gut is telling me to just go with the SSD, since I've always understood those to be faster and more reliable. Can someone shed some light on that?

Also, bonus question: they also give a third, much more expensive option below all that: RAID 0 Plus. I have no clue as to what benefits that might have. Any help on that option would be greatly appreciated as well.

Comment: RAID 0. Basically makes two hard drives function as one logical hard drive. So, in theory, you get twice the read and write performance minus any bottlenecks. I would go with the one SSD and upgrade to a second if you need more space down the line. Unless you know you need RAID0, just avoid it.

Comment: You are misunderstanding. RAID is independent of SSD. RAID is a technology to increase storage space and/or provide higher reliability/speed. RAID0 is about speed.  **The disks in the Dell options are not identical but are all SSD** Each RAID0 option is 2 (SSD)disks of half the size of the SSD option.  The advantage is speed. The disadvantages are complexity and reduced expandability. I would go for the SSD option, as those SSDs are fast ones and unlikely to be a significant bottleneck. (Please don't take offense, but if you need to ask the question, you should not be using RAID0)

Comment: [Alienware: What Is RAID?](https://www.dell.com/support/article/en-uk/sln117856/alienware-what-is-raid?lang=en)